# How can I tell whether the bad sectors are physical or logical?

Tags: hard-drive

My HDD has a crap ton of bad sectors, I'm scared if they're physical or logical, is there any way I can tell the difference?

Comment: Backup now and get new hard drive.

Answer (score 3):

Bad sectors are not logical. It will always be physical and possibly symptoms of a slowly failing hard drive. There is no question of differentiating between physical or logical because it's always physical. Hope this answers your question and I'd soon get a new hard drive if I were you.